# JS Input text convert value to integer/number/numeric for comparison

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, integer

Cannot in any way convert an input text's value to numeric! Have tried JS Number(input.val()) also parseInt(input.val(),10) also the unary +input.val() ...I need the input to compare it via a conditional statement if less or equal.

Anyone asking, I need input fields to be of type text, since Im using a plugin jquery knob. am aware of input type number.

Would really appreciate any heads up..can't be that there isnt a way to force such conversion.

** Update **
Myabe what I forgot to add, which I had read about and still didnt understand why, is that I'm iterating through inputs having the same class and then using this.val(), as a fix I've read an element must be called with its #id. in my situation can't do that.
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4qykfpde/)

```
 $('.hello').each(function () {
  var temp = $(this).val();
  console.log(+temp + "  , " + parseInt(temp, 10) + "   , " + temp +"    , "+Number(temp)+"   ,"+$(this).val());
 if (!$(this).val() <= 1) {
   $(this).val(--temp).trigger('change');
 }
```

});

Comment: _"Cannot in any way convert an input text's value to numeric!"_ You already know so many...

Comment: Can you provide the some code ? and where you face the problem ?

Comment: Right, show us the code, it should work well if only by looking at your descriptions

Comment: You've to store the value returned from the used conversion method into a variable. The value retrieved from an input element (type=text) is always a string, that can't be converted "in-place".

Comment: If `input` is the DOM `input` element, then note it does not have a `val()` method. It has a `value` property. Put  a `+` before it, and it will be cast to a numerical: `+input.value`. With jQuery: `+$(input).val()`.

Comment: @trincot tried your suggestion but still didnt work out for me, as can be seen in the fiddle.

Comment: I don't know what you think the problem is with the fiddle, but I have used it as input for an answer. Please check. Note that you used my suggestion (`+`) only in `console.log`, which is obviously not of any use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fiddle you provided has this `if` condition:

```
 var temp = $(this).val();
 if (!$(this).val() <= 1) {
     $(this).val(--temp).trigger('change');
 }
```

And in fact, the values in the inputs are decremented by this code. But it is almost by "accident" that this is the effect.

There are some problems with that `if` condition:

1. The result of `val()` is a string, while you seem to expect a numerical. You could cast it to a number by prefixing it with `+`. Although you do that in a `console.log`, you don't use that result at all.
2. The negation (`!`) only applies to the value, not to the whole `<=` expression, because `!` has precedence over `<=`. So either you should use brackets to give `<=` precedence, or you should use `>` instead, without the `!` operator.

Here is the same code corrected:

```
 var temp = +$(this).val();
 if (temp > 1) {
     $(this).val(--temp).trigger('change');
 }
```

The effect of the code is the same: all values are decremented, because the values you have put in the inputs are all greater than 1 (20, 30, 40, 50).

[Corrected fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/173q0u1o/)

Comment: never late to learn more :) thanks for the detail, was aware of the wrapping up with round brackets for precedence, but didn't think it was needed in this situation. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Jquery? You don't need an explicit conversion:

```
if($("#inp").val() > 5){
alert("Greater than 5");
}else{
alert("Less than 5");
}
```

Comment: I am using jquery , yes, but my issue is with iterating through inputs with the same class and the nusing $(this).val(). Have read about switching to using just id's and that should fix it straight away, but I cant since at a later stage I'll have dynamically generated inputs;